# Jump to activity from Android preference activity

Tags: android, android-intent, gradle

I have an Android app with a `PreferenceActivity`, and one of the Preference entries launches one of my own activities (the "About" screen). The entry looks like this:

```
<PreferenceScreen android:title="@string/about.Title">
    <intent ... />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Also (and this is important), I use Gradle and a `.debug` application ID suffix for my debug builds. I install both the Play Store version and the debug version on my phone.

The question is: What kind of intent to use above? I know of two options, neither of which work:

1. Use an `android:action` intent with my own action string, and register that action string in my manifest with `<intent-filter>`.

   1. If I use `android:exported="false"` in the manifest, then the activity fails to load on Android 7.1 when both apps are installed. (I get "Complete action using ... No apps can perform this action".) It works fine if only one is installed (either).
   2. If I use `android:exported="true"`, then not only am I exporting an internal Activity, but when I tap the preference, *two* instances of the activity are pushed on the stack (one for each app). If I install only one of the two apps, then only one instance shows up.
2. Use the `android:targetPackage` and `android:androidClass` approach, but then I don't know what to use for the package, since it's different for the release and debug versions (because of the suffix). One solution is to have a copy of the `preferences.xml` file in the debug resource folder with only the package changed, but this is bug-prone.

I was using option #1.1 for years but it recently broke on my phone, and I suspect the 7.1 update is to blame. I've never had cross-talk between these two installed apps before!

This has to be a pretty common pattern! Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow this steps:

After you add preferences using

```
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
```

find your preference that you want to set onClick and define it by casting like

```
Preference pref = (Preference) findPreference("pref");
```

Then you can easily set its onClick using:

```
pref.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
        startActivity(new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class));
        return true;
    }
});
```